# Android: drawTextOnPath multiline

Tags: android, android-canvas

I current have a custom view that I override the onDraw and draw an arc. I want to draw text within this arc. To do this, I use drawTextOnPath and this display curved text at the top of the arc. However, sometimes the text is quite long, so I want to allow it to go on to multiple lines.

I currently use code like this to draw on to multiple lines: -

```
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(s, 0,
                    s.length(), r);
            int yOffset=r.height() + textSpacing;
            int textStart=0;
            int numberOfLines= (int) (r.width()/arcWidth) + 1;
            for (int i=0; i < numberOfLines; i ++) {
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(s.substring(textStart, textStart + s.length() / numberOfLines),
                        childHolder.path, 0, yOffset, paint);
                yOffset+=r.height() +textSpacing;
                textStart=s.length()/numberOfLines;
            }
```

However, this obviously doesn't take into account how wide the text is further down the arc. Is there a way of doing this with using something like staticlayout/dynamiclayout (text does change a lot).

If anyone could point me in either something in android SDK I can use, or the maths to calculate the available width

Comment: yes, more or less, use `StaticLayout` with some fixed width and use `getLineCount` / `getLineStart` / `getLineEnd`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Because of I am drawing it in an arc, as you go on each new line, there available width is less, so I don't think staticlayout will work, because that is for a rectangle?

Comment: so calculate the length of your arc, and pass it as `width` param to StaticLayout ctor

Comment: Hi, Yeah I have the width of the arc, which isn't a problem at the top of the arc, this displays fine, it is more for lower down, if it has 3 lines, then the available width gets less and less, but the static layout will only have the width at the top of the arc.

Comment: `"width gets less and less"` what do you mean? see this simple view: http://pastebin.com/zENtPeJZ

Comment: Hi, sorry, don't think I have been explaining it well. See this edited code, it isn't quite working in the exact same way, but is essentially what I am talking about http://pastebin.com/Lr0rwpgz

Thanks

Comment: so instead of `StaticLayout` you need `Paint#breakText` called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code solved my issue: -

```
    PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, false);
    layout = new DynamicLayout(spannableText, spannableText, paint, (int) arcPathMeasure.getLength(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 0, true);
```

Thanks pskink!